# How to Get Clicked ListView Item

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am having trouble getting the clicked item in a `ListView`

MainPage.xaml

```
 <ListView 
                    ReorderMode="Disabled"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemClick="Section_ItemClick"
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">

                    <ListViewItem Margin="0,0,0,10" Background="LightGray">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/1.png" Width="94" Height="94"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="1" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>

                    ...
</ListView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void Section_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem itemId = ((sender as ListView).SelectedItem as ListViewItem);

        if (itemId != null)
        {
            .. do something ..
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(this.resourceLoader.GetString("NavigationFailedExceptionMessage"));
        }
    }
```

EDIT**

In further testing I've discovered that both `sender` and `e` are null when the event fires?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok this solved it (finally). Use the SelectionChanged event, and assign each ListViewItem a name via `x:Name`

MainPage.xaml

```
<ListView 
                    x:Name="SettingsHub"
                    ReorderMode="Disabled"
                    SelectionChanged="SettingsHub_SelectionChanged"
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
      ...
</ListView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void SettingsHub_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var itemId = (e.AddedItems[0] as ListViewItem).Name;
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `ClickedItem` first. One of the following should work (I am not sure which one will work because I don't have windows phone SDK installed right now):

```
var itemId = (e.ClickedItem as ListViewItem);
var itemId = (e.ClickedItem as Item);
```

then check for `null` reference:

```
if (itemId != null && itemId.IsSelected)
{ }
```

Also check the documentation for [`ItemCLickEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemclickeventargs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `itemID` returns null.

Comment: Perhaps `e.ClickedItem` instead of `sender`?

Comment: `var itemId = (e.ClickedItem as ListViewItem);` returns null as well.

Comment: In looking into this further, both `sender` and `e` are null when the event fires?

Answer (score 0):

## this was a mod I used

for a listView that has just stings in it. Im storing rss feed urls in a listview, hence the Method Name. Left debug in code to help.

```
    private void RSSItem_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" CALLED ITEM CHANGED ");

        //ListViewItem itemId = ((sender as ListView).SelectedItem as ListViewItem);
        int count = e.AddedItems.Count;
        string  itemStr = e.AddedItems[0].ToString();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" DOWNLOADING FEED URL : " + itemStr);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void DrivingHistoryListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var SelectedItem = (DrivingHistoryItem)e.ClickedItem;
        .....
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void DrivingHistoryListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var SelectedItem = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
    .....
}
```